Создание интерактивных иконок на каждой странице LaTeX
Тк я пишу большую книгу, то мне очень хочется реализовать красивое интерактивное меню внизу каждой страницы, а именно: кнопки, ведущие на след/пред страницу/section/subsection. У меня получилось написать простой код, работающий для след/пред стр/section НО НЕ ДЛЯ subsection хотя я все делаю по аналогии. Пробовал даже вводить сторонний счетчик для создания автоматического label для каждой subsection, но ссылки формируются некорректно тк при повторной компиляции счетчик уже на макс значении.
Код приложил и комментарии к нему.
Если получится, хотелось бы исправить недочет в моем коде, не сильно усложняя его. Потом хочу нарисовать красивый интерфейс.
p.s. Компилируйте дважды
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec, titlesec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia, textgreek}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref, lastpage, etoolbox, refcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \ifnum\value{page}>1
    \raisebox{0.75cm}{%
      \hyperlink{page.\the\numexpr\value{page}-1\relax}{\fbox{\strut Previous Page}} % Создание ссылки на предыдущую страницу путем вычитания из номера данной страницы 1
      \hspace{1cm}
      \hyperlink{section.\number\numexpr\value{section}+1\relax}{\fbox{\strut Next Section}} % Создание ссылки на следующий \section путем добавления к номеру даннной \section 1
      \hspace{1cm}
      \hyperlink{subsec.\number\value{section}.\number\numexpr\value{subsection}+1\relax}{\fbox{\strut Next Subsection}} % Создание ссылки на следующий \subsection путем добавления к номеру даннной \subsection 1
    }%
  \fi
}

\preto{\section}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}>0
    \label{section.\number\value{section}} % Создание \label для каждой \section в формате section.N . Где N это номер \section
  \fi
}

\preto{\subsection}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0
    \label{subsec.\number\value{section}.\number\value{subsection}} % Создание \label для каждой \subsection в формате subsec.N.M . Где N это номер \section и M это номер \subsection
  \fi
}



\begin{document}

\section{s1}
\subsection{ghjffgo} 


\lipsum[1-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo} 
%subsec.\number\value{section}.\number\value{subsection}\\
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo} 
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo} 
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo} 



\section{s2}
\lipsum[11-40]

\section{s3}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
subsec.\number\value{section}.\number\value{subsection}\\
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{ghjffgo}
\end{document}


